# How to get new data to automatically slot into correct column in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to move new data into an existing database with set columns. The existing database has a column for every possible type of data, but not all new entries contain all columns. So I can't just cut and paste because the data from the new spreadsheet will not align with the correct column in the existing database. Currently I have to move each column separately every time we get new data in.

Is there a way to insert the new data and have it arrange itself into the correct columns in the database?

Comment: First of all, when you say “database,” do you mean spreadsheet?  If not, what is it?  Secondly, how do you know what values go into what fields/columns?  For example, if you have the data `Jane,Smith,Felix`, how do you know whether Felix is Jane’s husband or her cat?

Comment: Thanks pnuts. That is what I'm looking for. but for some reason when I change it to use my workbooks it will only copy one entry for each row across all of my sheets. For example, if I have 2 sheets of data (in one workbook) to consolidate and the first sheet has 3 rows and the second sheet has 8 rows, my consolidated workbook after I have run the Macro will only have 8 rows and any overlapping rows will be missing. any ideas why?